# How to dynamically create linq code at runtime and get results

Tags: c#, linq, build

I have this LINQ code that returns sum of a column.
I have 10 columns in this table with these names : Role1, Role2, Role3 to Role10.

How can I **dynamically create LINQ code at runtime, run this code and get results** for all columns without repeating code?

for example :

```
decimal result = 0;
for(int i=0; i <=10; i++)
{
  result += STList.Where(c => c.Row_Role[i].ID == row.ID).Sum(p => p.Role[i]Current);
}
```

Comment: _What_ is `STList`? What type is _"this table"_
?
_

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
decimal result = 0;
result = STList.Where(c => c.Row_Role.Select(p=>p.ID).Contains(row.ID)).Sum(c => c.Row_Role.Select(p=>p.Current));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to using dynamic results to get linq query.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby?rq=1) will solve most dynamic linq problems.